# Eigenfunctions of the Laplacian

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am willing to offer a bounty for this one, so I will give you an exact idea of what I need:

I am looking for solutions of $$\Delta \Psi(r,\theta)=k^2\Psi(r,\theta)$$
where $k\in \mathbb{R}$.

Such that: $\Psi(r,\theta)=0$ for r approaching infinity. $\partial_r \Psi(r,\theta)=0$ for r approaching infinity and at some $R \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ we want to have $$\Psi(R,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} f(l)\frac{1}{R} P_l(\cos(\theta))$$
where $P_l$ is the l-th Legendre Polynomial and $f(l)=\frac{1}{2l+1}(P_{l+1}(\cos(\alpha)-P_{l-1}(\cos(\alpha))$.

I am only interested in solutions on $$\mathbb{R}^3\backslash B(0,R)$$.
Actually, you do not need to proof that you have found a solution. It would be totally sufficient to find a solution. It might be interesting to know that when we only have $r$ dependence, then the solution is given by something like $\frac{A e^{-r}}{r}$, where A is some constant.

This is the big task, now if you have troubles with the form of $\Psi(R,\theta)$, I am also interested in a solution, where you can replace the one given above by: $\Psi(R,\theta)=CR\cos(\theta)$, where $C$ is a negative constant. (The other conditions (like $Psi$ goes to zero when r approaching infinity, remain all the same).

The first one with an answer to any of both boundary conditions will get the full bounty.

Comment: The question is pretty much meaningless without a statement of a region of interest and boundary conditions.  The boundary conditions would then define the allowable values of $C$ and corresponding functions $\Phi$ valid through the region of interest.

Comment: okay, sorry. i thought that there is a possibly a general solution and i could try that choose the appropriate function later on by myself.

Comment: By the way, the title is also misleading.  You are looking for eigenfunctions of the Laplacian, very different from Poisson's equation.

Comment: corrected it. probably this makes it also more a functional analysis question.

Comment: I think the tags are OK.

Comment: just curious: do you think that my question has a solution, so that one can write down a solution?

Comment: I'm sure it does; I unfortunately do not have the time right at this moment to provide you with a carefully-thought-out solution.

Comment: okay, I would highly appreciate it if you remember this question and if you actually do find the time, could provide me an answer if nobody has answered it before.

Comment: I don't think your equation has any non-trivial solutions, at least not with Dirichlet boundary conditions. In this case integration by parts shows that $\langle \Delta u, u \rangle \le 0$ for all $u \in H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$ so that there cannot be a positive eigenvalue $C \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: and since it works for having only r dependence, I was quite confident that it could work in this case too.

Comment: Since $\widehat{\Delta f}(\xi)=-4\pi^2|\xi|^2\hat{f}(\xi)$, eigenvalues to $\Delta$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are usually non-positive.

Comment: Okay, then you are invited to do it with a negative sign in front of the $k^2$, maybe this gives us some idea, how the solution might look like.

Comment: There are no smooth solution for the PDE over all $\mathbb{R}^3$ if $|\Psi \nabla \Psi|(r,\theta)$ falls off faster than $1/r^2$ as $r \to \infty$.
However, if you accept solution which is singular as $r \to 0$, you can "construct" a solution by expanding $\Psi$ using [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1). If I'm not mistaken,
the expansion is:
$$\Psi(r,\theta) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{f(l)}{\sqrt{rR}}\frac{K_{l+\frac12}(kr)}{K_{l+\frac12}(kR)}P_{l}(\cos\theta)$$

Comment: Actually I do have a question to the comments so far: you are arguing that the laplacian does not have positive eigenvalues, but would you agree that in the case when we only have r dependence, he actually does have positive eigenvalues? So is this only a problem caused by the dependence on r and theta now?

Comment: Notice also, that I do not want to find a solution that is defined on the whole space. Probably, achille hui you have found a solution, but based on your comment I have some troubles to understand what you actually have found there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The eigenfunctions can be found by separation of variables, 
and are of the form 
$${\psi}_{l m}(r,\theta,\phi) =
    \left\{
        \begin{array}[c]{l}
        {i_l}(k r) \\
        {k_l}(k r)
        \end{array}
    \right\}
    \left\{
        \begin{array}[c]{l}
        P_{l}^{m}(\cos \theta) \\
        Q_{l}^{m}(\cos \theta)
        \end{array}
    \right\}
    \{ e^{\pm i m\phi} \},$$
where the $i$s and $k$s are modified spherical Bessel functions.
($i_l(z) = \sqrt{\pi/(2z)}I_{l+1/2}(z)$ and similarly for $k$, where $I$ and $K$ are the modified Bessel functions.)
The $P$s and $Q$s are Legendre functions.
$\{e^{\pm i m\phi}\}$ should be read, for example, as "a linear combination of $e^{i m\phi}$ and $e^{-i m\phi}$."

We are interested in solutions with the following properties: They

1. vanish at infinity;
2. are well-behaved functions of $\theta$;
3. have no $\phi$ dependence.

Asymptotically, $i_l(z) \sim e^z/(2z)$ and $k_l(z)\sim \pi e^{-z}/(2z)$. 
In addition, $Q_l(\cos\theta)$ diverges for $\theta = n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. 
Thus, the solutions are of the form 
$$\psi_l(r,\theta) = a_l k_l(k r) P_l(\cos\theta),$$
where $a_l$ is some constant dependent only on $l$. 
It can be shown that 
$\lim_{r\to\infty}\partial \psi_l(r,\theta)/\partial r = 0$, 
so we need only match the remaining boundary condition.

The function of interest is a linear combination of the $\psi_l$s, 
$$\Psi(r,\theta) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty a_l k_l(k r) P_l(\cos\theta).$$
Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Psi(R,\theta) &=& \sum_{l=0}^\infty a_l k_l(k R) P_l(\cos\theta) \\
&=& \sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{f(l)}{R}P_l(\cos\theta)
\end{eqnarray*}
and so 
$$a_l = \frac{f(l)}{R \, k_l(k R)}.$$

**The second boundary condition**

To satisfy the boundary condition $\Psi(R,\theta) = C R\cos\theta$ we need only the $l=1$ term, since $P_1(\cos\theta)=\cos\theta$. 
We find 
$$\Psi(r,\theta) = \frac{C R k_1(k r)\cos\theta}{k_1(k R)}  
= \frac{C R^3(1+k r)e^{-k(r-R)}\cos\theta}{r^2(1+k R)}.$$

**Derivation of eigenfunctions**

In spherical coordinates we have 
$$\frac{1}{r^2}(r^2 \psi_r)_r + \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}(\psi_\theta \sin\theta)_\theta + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2\theta}\psi_{\phi\phi} - k^2\psi = 0,$$
where subscripts denote partial differentiation. 
Letting $\psi(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$ 
and multiplying by $r^2\sin^2\theta/(R\Theta\Phi)$ we find 
$$\frac{\sin^2\theta}{R}(r^2 R')' + \frac{\sin\theta}{\Theta}(\Theta'\sin\theta)' + \frac{1}{\Phi}\Phi'' - k^2r^2\sin^2\theta = 0.$$
Since $\Phi''/\Phi$ depends only on $\phi$ and the other terms on $r$ and $\theta$, $\Phi''/\Phi$ must be constant. 
We are looking for oscillatory solutions in $\phi$. 
Thus, 
$$\begin{equation*}
\Phi''/\Phi = -m^2,\tag{1}
\end{equation*}$$
so 
$$\Phi(\phi) = \left\{e^{\pm i m\phi}\right\}.$$

Now we must solve 
$$\frac{1}{R}(r^2 R')' + \frac{1}{\Theta\sin\theta}(\Theta'\sin\theta)' -\frac{m^2}{\sin^2\theta} - k^2r^2 = 0.$$
The first and fourth term depend on $r$ and the rest on $\theta$, 
therefore, 
$$\frac{1}{R}(r^2 R')' - k^2r^2 = l(l+1)$$
for some constant $l$. 
Rewriting this we find 
$$\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{r^2}(r^2 R')' - \left(k^2 + \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}\right)R = 0.\tag{2}
\end{equation*}$$
This is the modified spherical Bessel differential equation with solutions
$$R(r) =     
    \left\{
        \begin{array}[c]{l}
        {i_l}(k r) \\
        {k_l}(k r)
        \end{array}
    \right\}.$$

Lastly we must solve 
$$\frac{1}{\Theta\sin\theta}(\Theta'\sin\theta)' -\frac{m^2}{\sin^2\theta} +l(l+1) = 0.$$
Letting $x = \cos\theta$ we find the associated Legendre differential equation, 
$$\begin{equation*}
(1-x^2)\Theta_{xx} - 2x \Theta_x + \left(l(l+1)-\frac{m^2}{1-x^2}\right)\Theta = 0,\tag{3}
\end{equation*}$$
with solutions 
$P_l^m(x)$ and $Q_l^m(x)$, the associated Legendre functions. 
We have 
$$\Theta(\theta) =    
    \left\{
        \begin{array}[c]{l}
        P_{l}^{m}(\cos \theta) \\
        Q_{l}^{m}(\cos \theta)
        \end{array}
    \right\}.$$

Comment: This seems to be the solution found by @achillehui.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your initial solution or did you actually calculate it by yourself?

Comment: @Lipschitz: This is something I have calculated myself. In Mathews and Walker's *Mathematical Methods of Physics* (2nd ed) they go over the related problem $(\nabla^2+k^2)X = 0$ in detail starting on page 226. The solution to your problem can be found by transforming the solution found there, $k\to ik$.

Comment: thank you! you have earned the bounty

Comment: @Lipschitz: Glad to help. Cheers!