# Perturbation theory PDEs

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I have the solution of a PDE of the form: $$ \Delta \Psi(r,\theta, \phi) = k \Psi(r,\theta,\phi)$$
on a set $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash B(0,R)$.

Hence, the actual solution is known there!
Regarding this, you might have a look at: [Related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451132/eigenfunctions-of-the-laplacian)
Notice, that my solution is bounded and vanishes at infinity!
Now I want to consider an additional small perturbation
$$ \Delta \Psi(r,\theta, \phi) = k \Psi(r,\theta,\phi) + \epsilon \Psi(r,\theta,\phi)^2.$$

Of course, I suspect that you cannot analytically solve this PDE anymore, but is it possible to come up with some kind of perturbation theory(if it is difficult to answer this question with mathematical rigour, you are invited to argue with handwaving).

Comment: Naively (as a physicist), one would write $\Psi=\Psi_0+\epsilon \Psi_1$. Replace in original equation assuming $\Psi_0$ solves original equation. Get a new (linear) equation for $\Psi_1$ involving r.h.s. with (known) $\Psi_0^2$… iterate?

Comment: okay, since the known solution is a series(see related article), this could make it hard to determine $\Psi_0^2$.

Comment: But your question claims  actual solution is known, so I it is fair to assume the square is known too?

Comment: okay let's see, you recommend looking at $\Delta \Psi_1 = k \Psi_1 + \Psi_0^2$, right? Btw, do you know how to threat this extra term now? Probably, there exists something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters for PDEs too?

Comment: @Lipschitz: yes it does.

Comment: could you give me just a reference?- First, I want to thank you two. Also, if anybody here knows how to make this perturbation theory rigorous, feel free to answer.

Comment: @Lipschitz it is rigorous! At least for a physicist :-)

Comment: You can treat this equation by means of the method of sub- and super-solutions. I don't know if this can be referred to as a "perturbative method", but you can judge by yourself by looking at Evans's book on PDEs, §9.3

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I had a look at it, afais this is about existence of solutions of PDEs, how would it help me finding an approximate solution?

Comment: If you look at the proof it constructs the solution by means of an iterative process. This yields a sequence which must converge because of monotonicity and the pointwise limit is a solution to your problem. I know that this is a bit vague but it really is simpler than it looks.

Comment: well, in this example we look at $-\Delta \psi = f(\Psi)$, where $ f $ is smooth with and we have Dirichlet boundary conditions. In my example we look at $\Delta \psi = f(\Psi)$ (notice, that this has some consequences on $f$ if we multiply by (-1))and the solutions only exists outside a compact ball around the origin. So my question would be: Do you know that we can transfer this method to this problem or do you think it?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro If you are able to give a few details, I would accept your answer, as it is exactly what I asked for and thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll try, but you need to give me some time as I am rather busy right now. Thanx

Comment: No problem and thanks in advance!

Comment: @Lipschitz could you please explain to me why my answer is not answering your question?

Comment: Hi, in principle yes, it explains the perturbation step, but Giuseppe Negro wanted to give a proof why this perturbations works and therefore I wanted to wait for his answer in order to pick the best one.

Comment: It obeys the original equation at order ϵ^2 so that is more or less the definition of a perturbative solution. Note that the method would also work for the full blown problem of Ψ(r,t,p) it would just be more messy.

Comment: by "why this perturbation works" I meant that he wants to prove that the perturbation converges to the exact solution.

Comment: If you apply the above procedure iteratively n times it will provide you with a solution up to order ϵ^n. What would be a converged solution in your view? Compared to a numerical solution?

Comment: I would argue this was not your original post.

Comment: Hi, I see that you were waiting for my answer. I have not forgot this question but still found no time to revise Evans's book. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me simplify your problem to a purely radial one for the sake of simplicity.

Let us write $\Psi=\Psi_0(r)  + \epsilon \Psi_1(r)$
and first solve for $\Psi_0$.

The solution is (If I believe mathematica)
$\Psi_0(r)=\frac{c_1 e^{-\sqrt{k} r}}{r}+\frac{c_2 e^{\sqrt{k} r}}{2 \sqrt{k} r}$

Now I can plug this solution into the linearized first order (in $\epsilon$) equation

$\nabla^2 \Psi_1- k\Psi_1 =\Psi_0^2$, which again if I trust mathematica,

$\frac{e^{-\sqrt{k} r} \left(-4 c_1^2 k \text{Ei}\left(-\sqrt{k} r\right)-4 c_2 c_1 \sqrt{k}
   \text{Ei}\left(\sqrt{k} r\right)+e^{2 \sqrt{k} r} \left(4 c_1^2 k \text{Ei}\left(-3 \sqrt{k}
   r\right)+4 c_2 c_1 \sqrt{k} \text{Ei}\left(-\sqrt{k} r\right)+c_2^2 \text{Ei}\left(\sqrt{k}
   r\right)+4 c_4 k\right)-c_2^2 \text{Ei}\left(3 \sqrt{k} r\right)+8 c_3 k^{3/2}\right)}{8 k^{3/2}
   r}$

where $Ei(z)$ gives the exponential integral function.  The first order solution is 
therefore $\Psi_0(r)+\Psi_1(r)$ given above (it seems to obey the original equation at order $\epsilon^2$).

Now one would follow the same path to solve the more general problem, while properly accounting for the boundary conditions, order by order.